# NLP for reliable text classification on raspberry pi

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, classification, text-classification

Trying to get up and running my very own smart room.

As of now the system is on raspi 3, Google STT, naive bayes for text classification, PoS/NER by nlp-compromise, bunch of APIs, and then eSpeak. *(sure there are lot of other stages, but generally speaking)*

One thing which is **problematic** though is the **text classification**. Though, NB is doing a fair job but yeah there are issues.

Various text classification heavily rely on the fact that there would be large corpora to train with. And this makes sense, particularly if the application is news categorisation, for example.

But here we are talking about spoken language. If the sentence is `Tell me the weather`, there's only so much corpus you can generate for the variation in that simple statement. And still, find some other way to ask for the weather.

I don't think for each category there can be a large datasets of statements which would help to make the device clearly distinguish between commands.

Question

1. What can I do here, since more categories (or skillsets) would mean more similar statements.
2. Since it is a classification problem, even using SVM or RNN or any other trick should not make any such difference, even if I have to rig an external GPU for it. The corpus is about spoken sentences for various categories and the dataset can't be expected to be diversely educative for the system.

But honestly I am not clear of what could be a reliable method for classification, only for such specific purposes.

*PS - I have seen how Jasper works, but even that does not resolve to better "understanding" of categories, many times*